# Algorithm qgis:joinattributesbylocation not found

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatial-join, pyqgis-3, standalone

I would like to join attributes by location using standalone PyQGIS but I'm getting error. I have QGIS 3.16 installed on my machine.

```py
from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.16/apps/qgis", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

processing.run("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", {
            'INPUT':'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/bdot10k_bubd_a/bdot10k_bubd_a.gpkg', 
            'JOIN':'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/POLSKA/PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp',
            'PREDICATE':[1,5],
            'JOIN_FIELDS':['PNA','SIMC_id','SIMC_nazwa','ULIC_nazwa','Numer'],
            'METHOD':1,
            'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':True,
            'PREFIX':'',
            'OUTPUT':'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/projekt2.gpkg'})
```

And I'm getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py",
> line 108, in run
> return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)   File
> "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py",
> line 141, in runAlgorithm
> raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
> _core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm qgis:joinattributesbylocation not found

What is the problem?

Comment: What if you try running `Processing.updateAlgsList()` after `Processing.initialize()`? Additionally make sure that `%QGIS_PATH%\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing` is added to the PYTHON_PATH environment variable.

Comment: I solved that problem, thank you. I have another problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378188/selecting-only-10-records-from-layer-using-pyqgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I transfered folder "platforms" (C`:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\qt5\plugins\platforms`) to:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\bin
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\Python37
```

Answer (score 0):

### NNJoin

There is a more advanced plug with in QGIS plugin repo called NNJoin which joins two vector layers (the input and the join layer) based on nearest neighbor relationships.

please refer the page [NNJoinPlugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/)